# What there is to be learned from Dynkin's identification theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

By Dynkin's identification theorem I mean the following:

> Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be two probability measures on a measurable space $(\Omega, F)$. Suppose that G is a $\pi$-system on $\Omega$ such that $\sigma(G) = F$, where $\sigma(G)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ which contains $G$. Then the following are equivalent:
> 1.) $\mu_1 = \mu_2$, 2.) $\forall E \in F: \mu_1[E] = \mu_2[E]$

I am wondering what there is to learn from that theorem. I mean that is the theorem just a mathematical way to state the (quite obvious) property of functions that if $f:A \to B, g:A \to B$ are two mappings and $f(x) = g(x) \forall x \in A$, then $f = g$, to probability measures? I am wondering this because a probability measure is to my knowledge a *"relative"* function in the sense that it is a measure with finite total mass on a space $(S, F)$, where $F$ is **a** sigma-algebra on $S$, i.e. *relative* to the sigma-algebra of $F$. Is it then true that if two probability measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are equal on sigma-algebra $F_1$ on $\Omega$, then they might not be equal on a different sigma-algebra $F_2$ on $\Omega$? And if this is the case, then is the identification theorem any different from the property of functions I stated earlier?

Comment: The result is not trivial. What it says is that if two finite (or $\sigma$-finite) measures coincide in a collection of sets, an this sets generate the whole $\sigma$-algebra, then the two measure are in fact the same. The closed situation to this is for example the fact that is two uniformly continue functions in a real line coincide in the set of rationals, then the two functions are in fact the same. The sets of a $\sigma$-algebra could be too strange and worse of all, uncountable.Many times, a $\sigma$-algebra is generated by simples sets whose measures can be easily computed.

Comment: I think that in $2.)$ it is $\forall E \in G$. Otherwise the statement is trivial, I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is something very non-trivial going on here. The point is that to check that if two probability measures are equal on the $\sigma$-algebra $F:= \sigma(G)$, all you need to check is that they are equal on the generating set $G$.

In practise, you have much more control about sets in $G$ while an element of $\sigma(G)$ can look very 'ugly' or 'strange', so this theorem really makes life easier because it allows you to check equality on a nicer behaving subset.

I guess, if you are looking for an analogy with function equalities, it would be something like two continuous functions that agree on a dense subspace are equal everywhere.